# Nginx serve files on specific location from specific folder

Tags: nginx, config

I want NGINX to serve serve files from a `location` within a `server`.
As an example, I would like the url http://domain/ss/image.png to serve the file located within `/home/data/screenshots/image.png`

So far, I have attempted to use a regex in this manner

```
location ~ ^/ss/(.*) {
    root /home/data/screenshots;
    add_header content-type "image/png";
    try_files $1 /$1;
}
```

however it appears that this location is never reached, being handled by the location spefcified to `/` (which in my case is a redirect).

I am not flexible with renaming/changing any of the file structure of the project and want to achieve this result with just the NGINX config modification.

Comment: The `$1` will not match as it is missing a leading `/` and the final parameter of `try_files` is an internal redirect which will be handled by the `location /` block. You should try: `try_files /$1 =404;`

Comment: Hi! This appears to have solved my issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by [Richard's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200214/nginx-serve-files-on-specific-location-from-specific-folder#comment124096942_70200214) comment on the question, it appears that my regex approach was correct, however my issue was the usage of the `try_files` function.